# Installed PWA (on Chrome for Andriod) not rotating

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to play aroud a bit with screen orientation (locks, api), but it somehow won't work with my phone (Galaxy Flip 4).

I can rotate every page, but as soon as it is installed (as PWA, e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org), the orientation is locked to portrait and there is no way to change it. Rotating the phone, using the API, settings `orientation` in manifest, nothig is seaming to work. Any idea what could cause this behavior?

Testing it with different phones works seamless.

Comment: It seems your Galaxy Flip uses Android 13, right? There seems to be a bigger issue with Chrome-based installs of PWAs and their screen rotation with Android 13.